# Comparing and merging lists into tables

Tags: python

I have a list of unique strings (“sample IDs”). I also have a table that contains a subset of strings from the first list, each of them associated to another string (“sample characteristics”) in a following column (with spaces as separators). For example:

```
# All Sample IDs
id-001
id-002
id-003
id-004
id-005
```

```
# Subset of Samples, with associated characteristics string
id-001    'batch-1, yellow'
id-003    'batch-1, yellow'
id-005    'batch-9, blue'
```

```
# Desired Output
id-001    'batch-1, yellow'
id-002    NA
id-003    'batch-1, yellow'
id-004    NA
id-005    'batch-9, blue'
```

I am trying to combine both lists, creating a table where the first column will contain all "sample IDs", and the second column will contain the corresponding “sample characteristics” string for each ID or “NA” if the ID is not present in the second list.

I have been using this code to compare two lists of IDs, to find out which sample IDs will have available “sample characteristics” string:

```
with open('FILE1.txt', 'r') as file1:
        with open('FILE2.txt', 'r') as file2:
                same = set(file1).intersection(file2)
with open('RESULT.txt', 'w') as file_out:
        for line in same:
                file_out.write(line)
```

I have not been able to figure out how to get the “sample characteristics” for those IDs and combine them with the first list. I think using a dict should be the first step:

```
with open('FILE1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('FILE2.txt', 'r') as file2:
     data1 = file1
     data2 = dict(file2)
```

I do not know how to continue.

Comment: there's no example of your data here to see

Comment: Woah. You're trying to find the intersection of a set and a file pointer.

Comment: OP, have you tried running this code? How did that go?

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, I have tried running the first code, it worked. I am aware that the second code doesn't work, it's advice given by someone else as a starting point. I am sorry if this is a very basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere and I don't know what else to do besides ask.

Comment: @AndreaLaguillo You could start by showing us what your data looks like. I understand you are working with some IDs but it really matters how you have stored those IDs in your text file. Is it one per line? Is it all in one line? Is it actually a CSV? We don't know anything. Just your dysfunctional code that gives nothing to go on. Andrea, unless you help us, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I think the inputs/desired outputs are described sufficiently, but it takes a few reads and could certainly be clearer if an example was included. Going off of the verbal description, I've made an edit that you can review for accuracy.

Comment: @COLDSPEED IDs are stored one per line, and the file is a CSV. As for the characteristics file, I have a CSV file separated by spaces where each row looks like so `sample_ID sample_characteristic`. If it needs to be separated by commas I can change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
import csv

results = {}
with open('FILE1.txt') as file1:
    for id_num in file1:
        results[id_num.strip()] = None

with open('FILE2.txt') as file2:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file2, delimiter=' ')
    for row in csv_reader:
        id_num, characteristic = row
        results[id_num] = characteristic

with open('RESULT.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file_out, delimiter=' ')
    for id_num, characteristic in results.items():
        if characteristic is None:
            characteristic = 'NA'
        row = [id_num, characteristic]
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

This basically sets up a dict with all the id's from the first file as the dict's keys.

Then it walks through each line of the second file to update the dict for each id that appears.

Then it writes the updated dict to a new csv file.

Comment: This code gives an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 16, in <module>
    for id_num, characteristic in results.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems''`

Comment: Sorry. I assumed python2 syntax. I've edited to work for python3

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a downvote, but maybe because there isn't an explanation for what this code does? Otherwise, it looks good to me.

Comment: @matt p i added an explanation